# Lossing string data c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to build a messageQueue based around this messageStruct

```
struct MessageStruct{
    public: std::string msg;     // what is the msg
    public: int prior;           // how important is this msg
};
```

That lies in a MessageQueue that is needed to act like a vector/priorityQueue (self made version that is working fine), but I put a bunch of stuff on it, like so.

```
int size = 20;
// constructor takes number of entries to start with
MessageQueue * queue = new MessageQueue(size);
// used as a transport mechanism
MessageStruct * msg = new MessageStruct();
msg->prior = 0;
msg->msg = "queue exists";
queue->getMsg(msg);
// increasing size does not cause memory issue,
//  use for example of dynamic size.
... other stuff is happening
size *= 2;
for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++){
    msg->prior = 0;
    msg->msg = "creating thing " + ii;
    // puts this message in the queue,
    //  and increases queue size if needed
    queue->getMsg(msg);
}
... // other stuff is happening
msg->prior = 10;
msg->msg = "program terminated correctly";
queue->queueDump();
delete msg;
msg = 0;
delete queue;
queue = 0;
```

This code gets no errors, and all memory is being released without issue, though the output of this looks like this (I generate the output in xml for sanity):

```
<message> 
    <index>0</index>
    <msg>program terminated correctly</msg>
    <priority>10</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>1</index>
    <msg>init(). queue exists</msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>2</index>
    <msg>reating thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>3</index>
    <msg>eating thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>4</index>
    <msg>ating thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>5</index>
    <msg>ting thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>6</index>
    <msg>ing thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>7</index>
    <msg>ng thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>8</index>
    <msg>g thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>9</index>
    <msg> thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>10</index>
    <msg>thing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>11</index>
    <msg>hing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>12</index>
    <msg>ing </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>13</index>
    <msg>ng </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>14</index>
    <msg>g </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
<message> 
    <index>15</index>
    <msg> </msg>
    <priority>0</priority>
</message>
```

It looks like the strings are being generated and placed, but why are leading characters being removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to introduce a method to the code that converted an int to a string

```
//----------
// attempts to convert a int to a string
//----------
string toString(int value) {   // may need to specify std::
    string result = "";
    bool negative = false;
    if ( value < 0 ) {
        negative = true;
        value *= (-1);
    }
    do {
        string tmpstr = "0";
        tmpstr[0] += value%10;
        result = tmpstr + result;
        value /= 10;
    } while ( value != 0);
    if ( negative ) {
        result = "-" + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

then modify the line

```
msg->msg = "creating thing " + ii;
```

to be

```
msg->msg = "creating thing " + toString(ii);
```

this can be costly to do in repetition, but the only other option is likely to call a string builder that doesn't really save anything

Comment: I got here to review answers, but it seems you've been at stackoverflow for some time. So let me help you get to 100 points and ++ your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of errors here.

```
MessageStruct * msg = new MessageStruct();
msg->prior = 0;
msg->msg = "queue exists";
queue->getMsg(msg);

size *= 2;
for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++){
    msg->prior = 0;
    msg->msg = "creating thing " + ii;
   queue->getMsg(msg);
}
```

First of all, a style error.  "Get" is a verb typically used to mean "I want the object to give me something".  Your method "getMsg()" actually means "I am giving the object something", which will confuse anyone looking at your code.  You should rename this to "pushMsg()", "addMsg()", or something similar.  To be totally accurate, you shouldn't use abbreviations.  "pushMessage()" is probably the best name to go for here.

Next, you're making a basic error regarding pointers.  You allocate a single MessageStruct and then continually change its data.  You need to create a new struct for every piece of data you insert into your queue, like this:

```
MessageStruct * msg = new MessageStruct();
msg->prior = 0;
msg->msg = "queue exists";
queue->getMsg(msg);

size *= 2;
for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++){
    MessageStruct * anotherMsg = new MessageStruct();
    anotherMsg->prior = 0;
    anotherMsg->msg = "creating thing " + ii;
    queue->getMsg(anotherMsg);
}
```

(You can ignore this error if your implementation of MessageQueue creates a full copy of the struct you pass in via a pointer, but I'd seriously consider revising that design to more closely follow the behaviour of std::vector.)

Lastly, you can't append numbers to strings in C++ by using "mystring + mynumber".  In your code, this is a standard C-string:

```
"creating thing"
```

A C-string is an array of numbers that represent ASCII codes.  A simplistic way of thinking about how C deals with arrays is just to imagine that they are pointers to a sequential block of memory.  If I add an integer to a pointer what I get out is the memory address of that pointer plus whatever my integer was.  So, in this case, the strings you're getting out are:

```
"creating thing" + 0 = "creating thing"
"creating thing" + 1 = "reading thing" // Pointer + 1 gives a string starting at "r"
"creating thing" + 2 = "eading thing" // Pointer + 2 gives a string starting at "e"
Etc.
```

This is how strings and arrays work in C:

```
string + integer == string[integer]
```

I'm guessing that you're coming at this from something like C# or JavaScript background.  C and C++ aren't quite so helpful.

Comment: ok style point accepted, but on the second point of creating the messageStruct every time I need it is just a throwback to lazy initialization which can lead to memmory leaks like you have here. if your going to instantiate an object in a for loop scope then you should use [delete msg].

Comment: Technically you shouldn't be using "new" at all; you should create structs on the stack and let the scope end automatically clean them up for you.  Unless you have a really good reason (developing for an embedded system, for example), "new" is considered very bad C++ style these days.  There's no memory leak if your MessageQueue class retains pointers to your objects instead of creating copies.  That's how the stdlib container classes handle this situation - if you store pointers, you manually delete any objects you created when you get rid of the container.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you dismissed as working fine is most likely adding to the problem. In the code you've shown, you modify the same message object, okay, not a problem, but it is a problem if your queue implementation is not adding each message correctly. I would start there.

Comment: been checking that, and the queue object is adding what it is recieving. checking in realtime with breakpoints, and watches